Passing a lambda with capture into another lambda causing the capture to always happen (?)
Situation
A lambda h() always accesses non constexpr variable k.
If I use like if constexpr(false){h();} , k will never be captured.
But if I pass h() into another function g like g(h), k will always be captured even the constexpr condition is known at compile time to be false.
^ This is what I interpret. I may be totally wrong.
MCVE
https://wandbox.org/permlink/qmV1nsVWG6l62JlB
Test 1 is compilable.
Test 2 is uncompilable.
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include  <utility>

int main(){
    int k=3;
    //vvv test 1:: (compilable)
    //  #define g(h) if constexpr(t!=5){h();}
    //^^^ test 1
    auto f= [&]<int t>() {
    //vvv test 2:: (uncompilable)
       auto g=[&](auto h) {if constexpr(t!=5) {h();}  };
    //^^^ test 2
       g([&](){
          if  (k==5) { //: access 'k' non constant variable
          }else {
            int s=0;    
          }
       });
       return t+1;
    };
    constexpr int s=f.template operator()<5>(); //not access 'k' 
    int s2=f.template operator()<s>();// access 'k' 
}

Question

Why?  Please explain it and refer to some C++ rules.  I need to learn more.

How to make my code works like Test 1 but without my MACRO trick while maintain g's ease of use?


